# OpenStack: Keystone service stops immediately after starting

Tags: openstack

When restarting the Keystone service, it starts with a PID but within a fraction of second it stops. Checking the status immediately afterwards, it shows a different PID and when rechecking afterwards, it's dead.

```
root@hyper5:~# service keystone restart  
stop: Unknown instance:  
keystone start/running, process 37746  
root@hyper5:~# service keystone status  
keystone start/running, process 37750  
root@hyper5:~# service keystone status  
keystone stop/waiting
```

Comment: (1) Which version? Grizzly? Havana?  (2) Which OS are you running on?

Comment: Can you post the contents of keystone's log file to pastebin.ubuntu.com and post the link to your question. You can find the log file from `/etc/keystone/keystone.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue. All I did is removing 'persistence' from "driver = keystone.token.persistence.backends.sql.Token" and keeping "driver = keystone.token.backends.sql.Token" . After this perform service keystone restart. This enabled both ports 5000 and 35357 start listening.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to keystone is not getting started properly and therefore port 35357 is not in listening mode.
This seems to be anomalous behavior of service keystone. 
I am mentioning steps which have worked on my system for havana installtion on Ubuntu 12.04 Kernel version 3.2.0-67-generic. After a day of headache around this issue. Try these steps, preferably in the same order.

1) Remove keystone package:-

```
  apt-get remove  keystone
```

2) Reboot your system

```
 reboot
```

3) After reboot again INSTALL KEYSTONE.

apt-get install keystone

4) Check status of keystone service

```
 service keystone status
```

It will show start/running

5) Now do the necessary changes you want to do in /etc/keystone/keystone.conf

after making changes in conf file **DO NOT RESTART KEYSTONE SERVICE**

Use stop and start command to make an effect of restart but don't restart.

service keystone stop

service keystone start

For further help, pasting a dump of my CLI :-

http://pastebin.com/sduuFCL7

Answer (score 0):

OK the only thing that worked for me is commenting "*driver = keystone.token.persistence.backends.sql.Token*"  of the **[token]** section in the ***/etc/keystone/keystone.conf*** file